# Node.js - single app code, multiple runs with custom settings

Tags: git, node.js, repository

I'm going to start software as service app in Node.js. Is there any way to have one source code and many app instances? I wanna develop and commit just one repo, that changes will be visible in all of app instances? Of course user can set own config like database and vhost.
User files will be stored in his file system directory mounted to the vhost. Where will be his /her public files as images or download added from CMS.

Best, Mark.

Comment: if it's a SaaS app, why do you need multiple instances? Why does each user need an independent instance as opposed to sharing a single instance (or multiple load balanced instances)?

Comment: I'm trying to find a way to avoid duplicating of data. I can add node app files in every vhost and run each instance separately, but in this case we've got copies of this same app. Maybe should I do this? With git repositories everywhere and script for deploying all of them at the same time.